# How to search for a pattern in a file and store it in a variable using shell script? Please give an example

Tags: bash, shell, pattern-matching

suppose in a file if I have " Route : 8888" , I want to get the string after the pattern "Route :"

I have used sed command, but it is printing 8888 but I want to store it into a variable and use for further processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So store sed's output in a variable:

```
ROUTE_VALUE=$(sed ... <file.txt)
```

Where '...' is your sed command.

```
$ cat rt.sh
ROUTE=`sed -n 's/.*Route = \(.*\),.*/\1/p' data.txt`
echo $ROUTE
$ bash rt.sh
8888
$ source rt.sh
8888
```

Comment: The following is my sed command
sed -n 's/.*Route = \(.*\),.*/\1/p' data.txt

I did this as u suggested ROUTE=$(sed ... <file.txt)
But illegal variable. How should I declare it?

Comment: ROUTE=$(sed -n 's/.*Route = \(.*\),.*/\1/p' data.txt)
echo "$ROUTE"

this is giving illegal variable name

Comment: Okay, rename it to something, I've picked a random name.

Comment: Code:
ROUTE=`sed -n 's/.*Route = \(.*\),.*/\1/p' data.txt`

OUTPUT:
ROUTE=8888: Command not found

Comment: Unsure how you do it, I've added an example.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I used command source rt.sh rather than bash rt.sh  .. What is the difference

Comment: `source` reads commands and executes them in current shell. `bash rt.sh` runs bash as a separate process that executes the script.